# Why is DB an acronym and not abbreviation?

Tags: .net, fxcop, database, casing

According to the .NET framework design guidelines, they say DB is an acronym and cased as such.  But I thought it was an abbreviation of database?

Comment: It's definitely not an acronym. Acronyms are words you can pronouce, like LINQ or SOLID.

Comment: Matt Hamilton's comment is incorrect - the ability to pronounce acronyms does make one.  People just try to form them so they do for because it's a memorization technique.

Comment: An abbreviation is any commonly recognized shortening of a word - acronyms are special cases of abbreviations. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation  In any case, does it matter?

Comment: @Charlie: the question is pretty terse but, based on the tags, I'm guessing squi is getting FxCop warnings for some class/variable that contains "Db" in it. Still, this may be the most pedantic question ever: DB -- acronym or abbreviation?

Comment: Technically Matt is correct.  DB is an initialism. To qualify as an acronym it should be pronounceable as a word.  "dee bee" is not a word so DB is not an acronym.  However this is another case where popular misusage is overruling the dictionaries.  In the process we are losing what can be a helpful distinction.

Comment: Of acronyms, and initialisms: "There is no universal agreement on the precise definition of the various terms (see nomenclature), nor on written usage..."  from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym_and_initialism

Comment: For a source on this question see the section _Capitalization Rules for Acronyms_ in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx where is says "A property named DBRate is an example of a short acronym (DB) used as the first word of a Pascal-cased identifier."

Answer (score 14):

Originally it was "data base", then "data-base", and then just "database".  You can see all three used in [this paper](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=804439&dl=GUIDE&coll=GUIDE&CFID=49159668&CFTOKEN=43692002) and its citations.  Reference 4 is to E.F. Codd's 1974 paper "Recent Investigations in Relational **Data Base** Systems", reference 2 is to Don Chamberlin's "Relational **Data-Base** Management Systems" (1976), while reference 1 is to a paper in the ACM Transactions on **Database** Systems.

You see this sort of progression in English as a new compound noun becomes familiar.  Take a look at Google Books and type in "sky-scraper" to find century old references to the new type of building.

So actually DB is an **acronym** for the old "data base".  (It's not a portmanteau, which is a blending of two or more words, eg, "smog" is a portmanteau of "smoke-and-fog".)

Comment: E.g. web page --> webpage

Comment: Thanks for the great info! Given that dictionaries like www.m-w.com now contain "database" but not "data base". That was probably already the when the .NET framework was being written, so they should have considered it an abbreviation of "database".  Just still seems strange.

Answer (score 8):

Database is a [portmanteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) of "data" and "base"; that makes "DB" to be an acronym because it is the first letter of each word involved (even if the words are written as a combined word).

An abbreviation is usually the first few letters of the word IE: "abbrev." is the abbreviated version of "abbreviation".

Comment: And "Mr" is an abbreviation of "Mrister"? :-)

Comment: I prefer Esq. for "Esquire" myself :p

Comment: Well, no, not really: a portmanteau is a blend of two or more words, like "brunch" for breakfast-lunch and "Tanzania" for Tanganyika and Zanzibar.

Comment: @Jim: So "data base" > "data-base" > "database" isn't a blending of two+ words to you?

Comment: @Rexem: It is, sort of, but to linguists "database" is an "endocentric compound" (I just learned that in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_words! ;-).

Answer (score 4):

English is strange.

I think you'll find that 'data base' used to be two words, and slowly got merged over time, to one. The general process for merging words is

- Data Base
- Data-Base
- Database

In regards to the API, I think it's sometimes inconsistent anyway, so I wouldn't be too concerned with specific definitions. My preference is to always uppercase acronyms.

Comment: I was reading some paperback (paper back?) thriller from, like, 1996 in the loo a while back and the main character kept talking about the "data base" this and the "data base" that. I couldn't keep reading.

Comment: electronic mail, e-mail, email

Answer (score -1):

I would say abbreviation instead of acronym as database is one word. Interestingly DB is already very overused [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/DB).